# Last Angular 5 update gives me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: angular, console, syntax-error, token

I can't seem to fix this error that came after updating the version of angular with npm update.

Now even if I start a new project on Angular 5 with the command line :

```
ng new my-app
```

Before doing anything with the project, I have the following error in my console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

[image]

I have been working on several other projects for the last month with angular and firebase and this error was not going out.

Comment: is that error present when you open the page in Incognito mode? Sometimes chrome extensions interfere. Angular files typically end with `.bundle.js` so that doesn't look like an Angular file to me. Also, how are you building your project? With `ng serve`? I would check if the error is present on both dev and production builds.

Comment: thks JP for your reply. Using the Incognito mode doesn't remove the error. I am actually using ng serve to work on the project. But as you mentioned, deploying an angularfire project on firebaseapp.com removes it...

Comment: hmm. what happens when you clear the cache and delete cookies for localhost:4200?

Comment: Clearing the cache and deleting cookies doesn't remove the error. And using the enableProMode() on localhost:4200 also show the error... don't know what to do. Was wondering if I have a problem with my machine...

Comment: yeah, not sure either. What happens when you view in another browser?

Comment: I have the same error on Safari : [Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse error. (anonymous function) (is2:1) ". On FF, I don't think I see it. I just have a warning in the console : "[WDS] Disconnected!"

Comment: I have found that my macOS High Sierra is infected with a virus